# Virtualenv causing setuptools error

Tags: virtualenv, setuptools, python-venv

I am having trouble running a virtualenv, and I keep getting this same error code: "setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1"

I saw some pages talking about how this is a discrepancy between different versions of setuptools, but I've uninstalled and reinstalled virtualenv and setuptools in several versions to no results.  Does anyone know what's happening here?

```
Roberts-MacBook-Air:script Rob$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/Rob/Seedstages/script/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Rob/Seedstages/script/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /Users/Rob/Seedstages/script/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1004, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 969, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Users/Rob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 910, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/Rob/Seedstages/script/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
Roberts-MacBook-Air:script Rob$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that Anaconda causes the conflict, though to be more specific, it appears as if Anaconda's virtualenv is the problem.  Running `which virtualenv` on my macbook (where I'm having the same problem) yields `/Users/me/anaconda/bin/virtualenv` while running it on the linux system I just tested this on yields `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`.

So, on OS X, I downloaded virtualenv using `/usr/local/bin/pip install virtualenv`.  This doesn't create a virtualenv binary (or it didn't for me) in the PATH folders, so I had to type this painfully long command:

> `sudo /usr/local/bin/python` ... {the path to virtualenv.py in the system python's site-packages folder} new_env

And that did it.  But that's ridiculous. No one wants to do that - even creating links would still be hacking it when you don't need to.

According to the ContinuumIO github page [on this very subject](http://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/305), the `virtualenv env` and `source /bin/activate` commands are replaced with `conda create -n env python=2.7` and `source activate env`.

Tested on my macbook (running Anaconda2 v4 on OS Yosemite) and it worked out.